# Uploading mp3 file results in XHR 404 error despite directory existing

Tags: javascript, ajax, upload, mp3

I am creating a web page where users will upload a selected mp3 file. I am trying to do this within JavaScript / AJAX like the following:

```
//File upload button
var uploadBtn = document.createElement("input");
uploadBtn.innerHTML = "Browse...";
uploadBtn.id = "fileToUpload";
uploadBtn.type = "file";

// Create a submit button
var submitButton = document.createElement("button");
submitButton.innerHTML = "Submit";
submitButton.id = "submitButton";
```

Once they select their file and hit the submit button (note that mp3File and formdata are global variables created elsewhere), this code is executed:

```
mp3File = document.getElementById("fileToUpload").files[0];
formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("mp3File", mp3File);
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", 'mp3_uploads/', true);
req.send(formdata);
```

I get this error each time:

> XHR POST [path to my website here]/mp3_uploads/ ---> HTTP/1.1 - 404 - Not Found

I get this error even though the directory exists on my server. Note that I can also upload mp3 files via a separate HTML file that has a form / references a PHP file, but I would really prefer not to do it that way if I can avoid it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

While the directory exists, it's not a script. And a directory doesn't accept a POST request, so you'll get a 404 error.

You should create a PHP script (or another server side language) that handles the file and saves the file to the directory.

Comment: Thank you. I switched it to use AJAX (which calls a PHP file), but it kept not working (and not even getting to the PHP file). I discovered the problem: Even if formData is not empty, and registers in the AJAX file, it will not send via PHP unless you explicitly create a form back on the JavaScript page. So I simply created an actual form on the JavaScript page, and that did the trick (not even needing the intermediate AJAX step because it can call the PHP file directly).

Anyways, thanks because ultimately this did help me solve it. :)

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to accept my answer if it helped you.